# Variance of a time integral with respect to a Brownian Motion function

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, itos-lemma

Let process
$$I_t = \int_0^t f(s) W_s \,\mathrm d s $$
where $W_s$ is standard Brownian motion. My question are the following:

We know that $\mathbb{E} (I_{t})=0$ for all $t$ and $f$ a integrable function. Is there a general formula for the second-order moment i.e. $\mathbb{E}(I_{t}^2)$ ?

Thank you in advance for any comments, help, remarks or references related to this issue.

Comment: $f$ is stochastic?

Comment: No, it's a deterministic function.

Answer (score 6):

Using Fubini's argument, assuming that $f$ is deterministic

$$E(I_t^2) = E\left(\int_0^t f(s) W_s ds\int_0^t f(u) W_u du\right)=\int_0^t\int_0^t{f(s)f(u)min(s,u)duds}$$

If  $f$ is continuous(even piece wise) you can prove that $I_t$ is normally distributed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I still have a doubt since for $f(t)=1$ we find a variance equal to $\frac{t^3}{2}$ and not $\frac{t^3}{3}$.

Comment: I think you have to recalculate it, your expected result is correct

Comment: Thank you for your precious help @Canardini

Comment: you are welcome, anytime

Answer (score 6):

As @Canardini pointed out,
\begin{align*}
E\big(I_t^2\big) &= E\left(\int_0^t f(s) W_s ds\int_0^t f(u) W_u du\right)\\
&= \int_0^t\!\int_0^t f(s)f(u)\min(s,u)dsdu\\
&= \int_0^t\left(\int_0^u f(s)f(u) s ds + \int_u^t f(s)f(u) u ds \right)du\\
&= \int_0^t \int_0^u sf(s) f(u)ds du + \int_0^t  \int_u^t uf(u)f(s) ds du\\
&=2\int_0^t uf(u) \int_u^t f(s) ds du\\
&=-u\left(\int_u^t f(s) ds\right)^2\Big|_0^t+\int_0^t\left(\int_u^t f(s) ds\right)^2 du\\
&=\int_0^t \left(\int_s^t f(u)du\right)^2 ds.
\end{align*}
Alternatively, note that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t f(s) W_s ds &= W_t \int_0^t f(s) ds - \int_0^t \int_0^s f(u)du\, dW_s\\
&=\int_0^t f(s) ds\int_0^t dW_s - \int_0^t \int_0^s f(u)du\, dW_s\\
&=\int_0^t \int_s^t f(u)du\, dW_s.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
E\big(I_t^2\big) &= \int_0^t \left(\int_s^t f(u)du\right)^2 ds.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your precious help  @Gordon

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @Gordon - can you please explain little further how the part after "Then" has actually come up?

Comment: By Ito's isometry