# Calculate Variance of a function of Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I was studying an example given in [Variance of a time integral with respect to a Brownian Motion function](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/50457/variance-of-a-time-integral-with-respect-to-a-brownian-motion-function?rq=1)

There we need to calculate the Variance of $I_t = \int\limits_{0}^{t} f \left(s \right) W_s ds$.

Then, it said that $E \left[ I_t^2  \right] = \int\limits_{0}^{t}\int\limits_{0}^{t}  f \left(s \right) f \left(u \right) \min \left(s,u\right) dsdu$

Can someone please help to understand the detailed calculation on how it can be arrived?

It is also stated that $I_t$ follows a Normal distribution. What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses the autocorrelation of the Weiner process ([proved in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884299/autocorrelation-of-a-wiener-process-proof)), ${\mathbb E}[W_s W_u] = \min(s,u)$

From your expression,
\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}[I^2_t] &= {\mathbb E}[\int_0^t f(s)W_sds \int_0^t f(u)W_u du]\\
&= {\mathbb E}[\int_0^t \int_0^t  f(s)W_s f(u)W_u ds du]\\
&= \int_0^t \int_0^t  f(s) f(u) {\mathbb E}[W_s W_u] ds du
\end{align}
where we moved the expectation into the integral as the Weiner terms are the only non-deterministic things

Then we substitute in the autocorrelation, and bingo!
\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}[I^2_t] &= \int_0^t \int_0^t  f(s) f(u) {\mathbb E}[W_s W_u] ds du\\
&= \int_0^t \int_0^t  f(s) f(u) \min(s,u) ds du
\end{align}

as required

Comment: Ahh and as for the normality of $I_t$ - remember that the sum of any number of normal variables is still normally distributed, even if they're correlated. An integration is the limit of a sum, so hopefully it's easy enough to believe that the sum of these brownians (weighted at each step by the local value of $f(s)$) must also be brownian